# Javascript cloneNode() does not work as expected with lists?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Why this example works as expected ([try it](https://codepen.io/peetonn/pen/ExYvwZz)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul id="myList1"><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li></ul>
<ul id="myList2"><li>Water</li><li>Milk</li></ul>

<p>Click the button to copy an item from one list to another.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var itm = document.getElementById("myList2").lastChild;
  var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(cln);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

while if `<ul>` list is broken into multiple line, it doesn't work ([try it](https://codepen.io/peetonn/pen/mdbMBWO)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul id="myList1"><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li></ul>
<ul id="myList2">
  <li>Water</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to copy an item from one list to another.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var itm = document.getElementById("myList2").lastChild;
  var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(cln);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lastChild` will return the last child, even if it's a text node (that is, the white space between the last `</li>` and the `</ul>`). Use `lastElementChild` instead, to ensure that you select an element, and not a text node.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var itm = document.getElementById("myList2").lastElementChild;
  var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(cln);
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList1"><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li></ul>
<ul id="myList2">
  <li>Water</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to copy an item from one list to another.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

You could make the code even more concise by using `querySelector` to select it instead:

```
var itm = document.querySelector("#myList2 li:last-child");
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var itm = document.querySelector("#myList2 li:last-child");
  var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(cln);
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList1"><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li></ul>
<ul id="myList2">
  <li>Water</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<p>Click the button to copy an item from one list to another.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```